# Show linear independence of eigenvectors of $T:V\rightarrow V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose that $V$ is a linear vector space and that $T$ is a linear map from $T:V\rightarrow V$. Suppose further that the vectors $\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2}$ and $\vec{u_3}$ satisfy:
> $$T(\vec{u_1})=2\vec{u_1}$$
> $$T(\vec{u_2})=3\vec{u_2}$$
> $$T(\vec{u_3})=\vec{0}$$
> Show that $\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2}$ and $\vec{u_3}$ are linearly independent.

**Big assumption that I am not sure how to justify: $\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2},\vec{u_3}\ne \vec{0}$**

If $V$ is a vector space $R^n$, then it seems obvious that the $\vec{u_i}, i\in\{1,2,3\}$ are eigenvectors with three different eigenvalues, therefore they must be linearly independent. This can be shown:

$$a_1\vec{u_1}+a_2\vec{u_2}=0\quad (1)$$
$$T(a_1\vec{u_1}+a_2\vec{u_2})=2a_1\vec{u_1}+3a_2\vec{u_2}=0\quad (2)$$
$$(2)-2(1)=0\Leftrightarrow a_2\vec{u_2}=0$$
Since $\vec{u_2}\ne \vec{0}\Rightarrow a_2=0\Rightarrow a_1=0$. $\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2}$ are linearly independent.

All three vectors:

$$a_1\vec{u_1}+a_2\vec{u_2}+a_3\vec{u_3}=0$$
$$T(a_1\vec{u_1}+a_2\vec{u_2}+a_3\vec{u_3})=2a_1\vec{u_1}+3a_2\vec{u_2}=0$$
Since $\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2}$ are linearly independent $\Rightarrow a_1,a_2=0\Rightarrow a_3=0$ if $\vec{u_3}\ne \vec{0}$

My questions:

1. Is my initial assumption correct and how to prove it?
2. Is this solution valid for all linear vector spaces?

Comment: You have to assume $u_i \neq 0$, otherwise the statement is false.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why, $\vec{u_i}=0$ does satisfy the three initial equations doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but if any one of the $u_i$ is zero, then the three vectors are not linearly independent.

Comment: The title uses the word, *eigenvector*. Part of the definition of eigenvector is that it isn't the zero vector. So if you insist on your vectors being eigenvectors, then it's automatic that they aren't the zero vector.

Comment: Does my comment work for you, Erik?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm not sure where the book meant it as eigenvectors, but that was my initial assumption. But from the resonse here I'm confident in the fast that the initiall statement is false if they are not.